# Ajax file upload temp directory

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

On the change of an input type file, I'm attempting to upload the file via ajax (not via form submit), move the file to a temp directory of my choosing, pass back then the path to that temp file then process. I'm using CentOS Web Panel as the platform, my ajax code works correctly

```
 $(document).on("change", '.dropify', function() { 
      var myFormData = new FormData();
       var fil = this.files[0];
       myFormData.append('file', fil);
        console.log(myFormData);
        $.ajax({ 
            url: 'classes/images/upload.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'text',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: myFormData,
            success: function(response) { 
                console.log(response);
            }
            
        });
        
    });
```

When this file gets to PHP it is going into the `sys_temp_dir` that I cannot move the file from via `move_uploaded_file()`, how can I get this to use the `upload_tmp_dir`? or force it to upload to another directory entirely? I'd rather not use the sys temp dir as I have sessions etc living in it. PHP below for reference.

```
if (isset($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
    if (0 < $_FILES['file']['error']) {
        echo 'Error during file upload' . $_FILES['file']['error'];
    } else {
        if (file_exists('images/uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name'])) {
            echo 'File already exists : images/uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name'];
        } else {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'images/uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name']);
            echo 'File successfully uploaded : images/uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name'];
        }
    }
} else {
    echo 'Please choose a file';
}
```

example of error log below

> [Mon Jul 17 13:01:25.742990 2017] [:error] [pid 212450:tid 139781212186368] [client 192.168.10.88:56517] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(images/uploads/logo.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/***/public_html/classes/images/upload.php on line 13, referer: http://***/fragrances-new.php?
>
> [Mon Jul 17 13:01:25.743071 2017] [:error] [pid 212450:tid 139781212186368] [client 192.168.10.88:56517] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpcvmedN' to 'images/uploads/logo.jpg' in /home/***/public_html/classes/images/upload.php on line 13, referer: http://***/fragrances-new.php?

Comment: Why can't you move it? Errors?

Comment: @JayBlanchard updated with error

Comment: Change your paths to use absolute paths. If the folder `images/` exists in the same folder as your script, use: `__DIR__ . '/images/uploads/` instead. (`__DIR__` will give you the absolute path to the file it's written in). If your file gets included in another file, then all relevant paths will be relevant from the file that does the including, not the included file.

Comment: Check what `move_uploaded_file()` returns and also dump the full path to the moved file and see that all looks correct.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson seems to have solved it, couldn't see the wood for the trees

Comment: _“how can I get this to use the `upload_tmp_dir`?”_ – by specifying a value for that setting in your PHP configuration. And FYI, your code is _dangerous_, because you trust the file name as it is send by the client. You need to go read up on what is called _path traversal attacks_.

Comment: @CBroe The code is just for a local offline tool, nothing being exposed to harms way. I'm fairly sure using upload_tmp_dir works with or without a value, as it will just default, it was in regards to using upload_ vs system_. solution has been reached

Comment: _“I'm fairly sure using upload_tmp_dir works with or without a value”_ – if you do not specify a value, _then_ it does fall back to the system temp dir.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to move file from one folder to another

```
if(!is_dir($destination_folder)) {
   mkdir($destination_folder, 0777,true);
}

if(copy($source_folder, $destination_folder)) {
   unlink($source_folder);
}
```

It works for me..

Comment: this was not the nature of the question, problem was solved in comments

Answer (score 0):

you just set your js file like this,then you will get all form data

```
 $(document).on("change", '.dropify', function() { 
   var myFormData = new FormData(document.getElementById("form-id"));


    $.ajax({ 
        url: 'classes/images/upload.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'text',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: myFormData,
        success: function(response) { 
            console.log(response);
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: The OP's issue isn't uploading the file, but rather _moving_ the file in the back end, after it's been uploaded.